# What is use of ci_session in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

As all you know in codeigniter we are using ci_session by two different ways. One is database and another one is files. In both we are storing id, ip_address, timestamp and data.

Please see the screenshot

[image: screenshot]

I would like to know two questions.

1. What is the use of ci_session?
2. What is the use of fields id, ip_address, timestamp and data?

Please explain this. It will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked PHP documentation about sessions and CI documentation about session library already?

Comment: Yes i checked @Tpojka

Comment: Because all of fields are covered there already.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is stateless, so sessions enable you to keep track of a user as they journey through your site, via multiple http requests.

The IP address is used to match the current users IP to what the session is expecting it to be. This helps for session security, but can be problematic for certain ISP's so is not enabled by default.

The timestamp is important for session expiry.

Data is used to store session data, like what is in a shopping cart, or if they are an admin etc.

This is all covered in great detail in the documentation: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

It is also covered in great detail in general PHP session handling:
http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Without sessions, your website experience would be one stand alone and disassociated page after another.

Answer (score 0):

very very important -- this value here for CI sessions config

sess_match_ip

keep that as FALSE. matching IP is not relevant any longer. mobile hotspots and other ways of connecting to the internet can update the IP every few minutes. in other words the users IP address is going to change and thats fine.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon user's IP address is the root cause of the problem. We are living in a dynamic world where a user roams around all the time. Its not 1998 where whole family used to have only 1 computer tied with 1 single IP.

In short make "sess_match_ip" as false. End of the story.